# On ajax response return false doesn't work and form doesn't cancel submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am facing issue, i f i am using ajax call, the return false not working.. 
and form submitted sucessfully.. I want that when i get response 1 form don't submit.. but on ajax request response form still submitting please help me..

here is code:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>do/add/review" method="post" name="dologin" id="dologinsubmitreview" onSubmit="return showpopupbox();">


function showpopupbox(){      
    var strs = $("form").serialize();
          var autocompleteURL = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>grahak/save_record_session?rnd=" + Math.random() +"&sessiondata="+ $("form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                    url : autocompleteURL,
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    method : "POST",
                    success : function(respd)
                    {
                        if(respd == 1){
                            $("#classiconpopupbx").show();
                            return false;
                        }
                        else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                });
}
```

Comment: Learn what means `asynchronous`

Comment: I want solution, this is compulsory to use ajax.. so please tel solution

Comment: return value in success callback is sent to the bitbucket

Comment: To back up what u_mulder meant. *Never* use the `async: false` option. It is deprecated and causes far more problems than it solves.

Comment: `return false` from within an AJAX success callback *will never prevent your form from submitting*.  You have to accomplish this a different way.  What is it you are trying to make happen here?

Comment: `preventDefault` would be something to look into ... as would some manners

Comment: @cale_b when a form submit i want to open a login popup but before that i want to save form data in a php session... so for that i am using this.. but when i am getting this issue that form submitted while i am using return false to not allow form to submit

Comment: @JaromandaX tried that as well but no success

Comment: what did you try? preventDefault (when using addEventListener) or manners?

Comment: just use e.preventDefualt();

Comment: ahhh ... here's the problem ... you want a synchronous return based on an asynchronous result ... much design needs to be rethunk

Comment: Yes, i just want that when i get response 1 than form don't submit, please provide a solution,i am working on this form last half hour and now fed up.. have to complete asap

Comment: One thing you can do is prevent the submit, *always*, then if your Ajax call returns true, post the form (and tell the code to allow it this time)

Comment: can you please share code so i can update and check.. as i am hectic..

Comment: Added a simple version below. There are several ways to do this.

Comment: ...and now updated it to look more like your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redesign your flow.  Javascript is asynchronous, which means that the form is submitted LONG before the AJAX call is complete.

Instead, use jQuery `on` to bind to the event, *capture* the event in the function, and run `event.preventDefault()` immediately which will stop the form from submitting.  THEN run your AJAX call.

In your AJAX success function, you'll need to decide what to do when it comes back "truthy".  Without knowing more about your desired outcome, it's impossible to advise how to handle that piece.

```
<!-- remove the inline onsubmit script handler -->
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>do/add/review" method="post" name="dologin" id="dologinsubmitreview">


// no-conflict safe document ready
jQuery(function($) {
    // Bind to the form submit here, and call event.preventDefault immediately
    $('#dologinsubmitreview').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        showPopUpBox(event);
    }

    function showpopupbox() {      
        var strs = $("form").serialize();
        var autocompleteURL = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>grahak/save_record_session?rnd=" + Math.random() +"&sessiondata="+ $("form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url : autocompleteURL,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            method : "POST",
            success : function(respd) {
                if(respd == 1){
                    $("#classiconpopupbx").show();
                } else {
                    // Do what you need to do here if the AJAX is true
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to prevent the submit, *always*, then if your Ajax call returns true, post the form (and tell the code to allow it this time):

For starters, don't mix inline event handlers with jQuery. The jQuery way is better:

```
// Start by not allowing submit
var allowSubmit = false;
$('form').submit(function(){
    var $form = $(this);
    // Only run the ajax if this is not a "real" submit
    if (!allowSubmit){
        // do the ajax call
        $.ajax({
           url: ...
           success: function(respd){
              if(respd == 1){
                  $("#classiconpopupbx").show();
              }
              else {
                  allowSubmit = true;
                  $form[0].submit(); // important - bypass jQuery event handler
              }
           } 
        });
    }
    // Conditionally allow the form to submit
    return allowSubmit;
});
```